# Remove camera distortion from part of image in C# using EmguCV

Tags: c#, crop, emgucv, rectangles, distortion

I am trying to remove distortion from a cropped version of my image. I know the x and y mapping matrixes for the full size image (1920X1080). The way I am trying to do this is to first create two new mappings that contain the part of the full size mappings corresponding to the crop rectangle and then apply them to the cropped image. However, the output is just a black image:

```
Matrix<float> matCam1Map1, matCam1Map2;
Matrix<float> matCam1Map1Crp, matCam1Map2Crp;

matCam1Map1 = new Matrix<float>(1080, 1920);
matCam1Map2 = new Matrix<float>(1080, 1920);
CvInvoke.cvInitUndistortMap(itsCam1.IntrinsicMatrix.Ptr, itsCam1.DistortionCoeffs.Ptr, matCam1Map1.Ptr, matCam1Map2.Ptr);

matCam1Map1Crp = new Matrix<float>(rectCam1Crop.Height, rectCam1Crop.Width);
matCam1Map2Crp = new Matrix<float>(rectCam1Crop.Height, rectCam1Crop.Width);

for (int i = 0; i < rectCam1Crop.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rectCam1Crop.Width; j++)
    {
        matCam1Map1Crp.Data[i, j] = matCam1Map1.Data[rectCam1Crop.Y + i, rectCam1Crop.X + j];
        matCam1Map2Crp.Data[i, j] = matCam1Map2.Data[rectCam1Crop.Y + i, rectCam1Crop.X + j];
    }
}

Capture capCam1;
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgCam1New = capCam1.QueryFrame().Copy(rectCam1Crop);
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgNoDistortion = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imgCam1New.Size);
CvInvoke.cvRemap(imgCam1New, imgNoDistortion, matCam1Map1Crp, matCam1Map2Crp, 0, new MCvScalar(0));
```

When I apply the full size mappings to the full size image, it works perfectly, but then I have to crop it. However, I am trying to make it faster by cropping it first, and then applying the mappings to the cropped image.

Does anyone know what may be the issue with my code?
Thanks

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? also sounds like when you `crop` you're not getting the actual cropped size but it still references the full image

Comment: Yes, I did. and no, it crops properly.